# XCode is not catching an error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, debugging

I'm using `setValue` to set properties in my class and get a very strange behavior. Upon trying to set a certain property, execution will break out my function and continue on from whatever called it. No compile errors and no errors in the debug console. Stripped down example here:

```
class User: NSObject{
  var profilePictureURL: NSURL?
  var contextId: String?
  var isOnboarded: Bool?

  func populate(data: [String: AnyObject]){
    for(key,value) in data {
      switch key {
      case "profilePictureURL":
        self.setValue(NSURL(string: String(value)), forKey: key)
      }
      case "contextId":
        self.setValue(String(value), forKey: key)
      }
      case "isOnboarded":
        if let boolValue = value as? Bool {
          self.setValue( boolValue, forKey: key) // Here is the problem line
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I set some breakpoints and run the app. When I call populate  with some user data, `setValue` works correctly for `profilePictureURL` and `contextId`. However once it reaches the `setValue` for the `isOnboarded` `Bool`, it just exists my function as if it was a `return` statement. No error, nothing in the debug window. I set a breakpoint on that line, verify that `boolVal` is in fact typed as a `Bool`, and attempt to step over the line. XCode then breaks out of this class, never sets that var, and stops on the next breakpoint (in another class). It just exits the function. It is bizarre.

If there was an error I'd expect XCode to notify me in some way. Just jumping execution to the next breakpoint makes this impossible to debug. I have no idea what is wrong with this code.

Is there anything I can add here to help determine what the problem is? Is this some kind of strange Swift/Xcode bug?

Edit: I did try clearing DerivedData and running Clean.

Edit 2: I was not able to figure this out. I did have some typos in my example code above, but they weren't relevant to the problem at hand. For some reason `setValue` behaves like a `return`, simply exiting the function with no error. I've fallen back to explicitly setting values like so:

```
self.contentId = String(value)
```

Comment: Check the curly braces in your switch-case... too many closing ones.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
var isOnboarded: Bool?
```

try

```
var isOnboarded: Bool = false
```

Also make sure your dictionary is structured something like this:

```
 let userDict : [String:AnyObject] = ["profilePictureURL": NSURL(string: "www.google.com")!,
                                         "contextId" : "anID",
                                         "isOnboarded" : true]
```

because I think you are probably setting "isOnboarding" to something other than a Bool and it is just exiting because

```
if let boolValue = value as? Bool
```

is returning false

tell me how that goes

Answer (score 0):

There's a few errors in your code. And simply using `if` does the job and is less error-prone in this case:

```
class User: NSObject {
    var profilePictureURL: NSURL?
    var contextId: String?
    var isOnboarded: Bool = false

    func populate(data: [String: AnyObject]){
        for(key,value) in data {
            if key == "profilePictureURL" {
                self.setValue(NSURL(string: String(value)), forKey: key)
            } else if key == "contextId" {
                self.setValue(String(value), forKey: key)
            } else if key == "isOnboarded" {
                if let boolValue = value as? Bool {
                    self.setValue(boolValue, forKey: key)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let source = ["profilePictureURL": "test.org", "contextId": 33, "isOnboarded": true]
let user = User()
user.populate(source)
```

---

But there's even better in my opinion: you don't need to loop over your dictionary, you should create values in the initializer, and use Swift structs. Example:

```
struct User {
    var profilePictureURL: NSURL?
    var contextId: String?
    var isOnboarded: Bool?

    init(data: [String: AnyObject]) {
        if let profile = data["profilePictureURL"] as? String {
            self.profilePictureURL = NSURL(string: profile)
        }
        if let id = data["contextId"] as? Int {
            self.contextId = String(id)
        }
        if let onboard = data["isOnboarded"] as? Bool {
            self.isOnboarded = onboard
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let source = ["profilePictureURL": "test.org", "contextId": 33, "isOnboarded": true]
let user = User(data: source)
```